# how to remove double quotes from json

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, jqplot

Im trying to plot a graph using jqplot.
First I load data from mysql and store it in an array.

```
foreach ($data as $row){
$values[] = array($row['date'],$row['value'],);
}
```

Then I `json_encode` it. Finally I place it on the the jqplot script.

The problem is that the `json_encode` outputs this:

```
[["12\/12\/2014","10"],["12\/13\/2014","20"],["12\/14\/2014","30"],];
```

But jqplot doesn't read number values wrapped on double quotes. The format must be like this:

```
[["12\/12\/2014",10],["12\/13\/2014",20],["12\/14\/2014",30],];
```

I've looked everywhere and can't seem to find the right answer, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the data for 'value' is stored in MySQL as a string. You need to convert it back to an integer. Also, remove the comma before the last end bracket for the array.

```
foreach ($data as $row){
    values[] = array($row['date'], (int) $row['value']);
}
```

Comment: Just added the (int) and that was it. Thank you very much!